# Double index in Perl, why is it so?

Tags: perl, arrays, multidimensional-array

with

```
@a=(6,3,5,7);

@b=(@a[0..3])[2..3];

print @b;

#print 57
```

but for

```
@b=@a[0..3][2..3];
```

I get a syntax error. Could someone explain why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The $a[1][2] for is used for 2 dimensional tables, actually it is short for $a[1]->[2]

so for that the first indexing needs to return a reference not a slice of an array.

The syntax error comes from the fact that Perl does not know how to dereference an array.

Comment: I guess it means the slice of an array is not list. If it were the second example would compile.

Comment: No, it means a slice is not a pointer to another array. In the first example you first evaluate a slice with the parentheses which results in a list, then you take a slice of that. In the second example perl tries to find the array pointed to by the first indexing, it finds an array and not a pointer/reference and fails.

Answer (score 3):

```
@a=(6,3,5,7);
```

This creates an array with 4 elements.

```
(@a[0..3])
```

This returns a list with the same four elements as `@a`.

```
(@a[0..3])[2..3];
```

This selects the last two elements from the 4-element list inside the parenthesis.

```
print( join( ",", @b ) );
```

This prints `5,7`, the last two elements in `@a`.

For fun try the following:

```
@a=(6,3,5,7);
@b=(@a[0..3]);
print( "\@b=" . join(",",@b) . "\n" );
@c=@b[2..3];
print( "\@c=" . join(",",@c) . "\n" );
```

Note that I used the Perl debugger to understand your program. You could do this, too, if you're not sure what Perl is actually doing from line-to-line.